# How to stop clustering a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've clustered a table using the following:

```
CLUSTER foos USING idx_foos_on_bar;
```

Now every time I run `CLUSTER` it reclusters that table (and all other tables with clustering) appropriately.

Now I want to stop reordering that one table (but still reorder all the others with a single `CLUSTER` command).

I don't see anything in the documentation about how to uncluster. Is this possible? Or do I have to completely drop and recreate the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-cluster.html

> When a table is clustered, PostgreSQL remembers which index it was
>   clustered by. The form CLUSTER table_name reclusters the table using
>   the same index as before. You can also use the CLUSTER or SET WITHOUT
>   CLUSTER forms of ALTER TABLE to set the index to be used for future
>   cluster operations, or to clear any previous setting.

I think older versions didn't support the `set without cluster` option.

Comment: The final command would then be `ALTER TABLE foos SET WITHOUT CLUSTER;`